# iOS Safari Action Extension kUTTypePropertyList is nil

Tags: ios, swift, action, extension-methods, safari-extension

Using the following action extension I am able to get the image URLs in a web page. However, when the URL is for a PDF file, then nothing. Property list is nil.

I have the following js file for the extension:

```
var GetImage = function() {};

GetImage.prototype = {
    imageURLs: function() {
        var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
        var imgSrcs = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
            imgSrcs.push(imgs[i].src);
        }

        return imgSrcs;
    },
    run: function(arguments) {
        arguments.completionFunction({
                                     "currentUrl": document.URL,
                                     "currentTitle": document.title,
                                     "content": document.body.innerHTML,
                                     "images": this.imageURLs(),
                                     });
    }
};

var ExtensionPreprocessingJS = new GetImage;
```

Then, within the actual action:

```
print("step a-1")
let item : NSExtensionItem = extensionContext!.inputItems[0] as! NSExtensionItem
let itemProvider : NSItemProvider = item.attachments?.first as! NSItemProvider

let propertyList = String(kUTTypePropertyList)

if itemProvider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(propertyList) {
    print("step a-2")

    itemProvider.loadItemForTypeIdentifier(propertyList, options: nil, completionHandler: { (item, error) -> Void in
        if (item != nil) {
            print("step a-3")
        }
        })
}
```

I am able to get the image URLs. However, when the page is a URL for a PDF file, then nothing. Property list is nil.

If I try without the js, then I get the public.url.

But, with the js, property list is nil...

Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

- By default if your extension properties are set to `NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebURLWithMaxCount` in Info.Plist > NSExtension > NSExtensionAttributes > NSExtensionActivationRule you will get the URL by default. Set it to `NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebPageWithMaxCount` to interact with the DOM
- Cast `item` in the callback to `NSDictionary` and access its `NSExtensionJavaScriptPreprocessingResultsKey` as follows

```
itemProvider.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: propertyList, options: nil, completionHandler: { (item, error) -> Void in
                guard let dictionary = item as? NSDictionary else { return }
                OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
                    if let results = dictionary[NSExtensionJavaScriptPreprocessingResultsKey] as? NSDictionary,
                        let urlString = results["currentURL"] as? String,
                    }
                }
            })
```